# ng-repeat inside another ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some JSON data that I'm loading into a list that has sub-lists inside said data. the JSON data is pulled from an API using a get call

```js
      "pet": [
        {
          "options": {
            "option": [
              {
                "$t": "hasShots"
              },
              {
                "$t": "altered"
              },
              {
                "$t": "housetrained"
              }
            ]
          },
          "status": {
            "$t": "A"
          },
          "contact": {
            "phone": {
              "$t": "emails only please"
            },
            "state": {
              "$t": "NC"
            },
            "address2": {
              
            },
            "email": {
              "$t": "techmed1@netzero.net"
            },
            "city": {
              "$t": "Charlotte"
            },
            "zip": {
              "$t": "28226"
            },
            "fax": {
              
            },
            "address1": {
              
            }
          },
          "age": {
            "$t": "Senior"
          },
          "size": {
            "$t": "M"
          },
          "media": {
            "photos": {
              "photo": [
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/1\/?bust=1475677088&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/1\/?bust=1475677088&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/1\/?bust=1475677088&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/1\/?bust=1475677088&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/1\/?bust=1475677088&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "1"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/2\/?bust=1475677088&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/2\/?bust=1475677088&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/2\/?bust=1475677088&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/2\/?bust=1475677088&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/2\/?bust=1475677088&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "2"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pnt",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/3\/?bust=1475677088&width=60&-pnt.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "fpm",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/3\/?bust=1475677088&width=95&-fpm.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "x",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/3\/?bust=1475677088&width=500&-x.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "pn",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/3\/?bust=1475677088&width=300&-pn.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                },
                {
                  "@size": "t",
                  "$t": "http:\/\/photos.petfinder.com\/photos\/pets\/36298811\/3\/?bust=1475677088&width=50&-t.jpg",
                  "@id": "3"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "id": {
            "$t": "36298811"
          },
          "shelterPetId": {
            "$t": "Domino"
          },
          "breeds": {
            "breed": {
              "$t": "Domestic Medium Hair"
            }
          },
          "name": {
            "$t": "Domino"
          },
          "sex": {
            "$t": "M"
          },
          "description": {
            "$t": "Domino is a sweet, talkative kitty with lots of purr-sonality. He never meets a stranger, and will let children carry him around in their arms. \nHe has tested positive for FIV, but we have had him in our rescue since 2009, and he has never had any health problems at all. He is neutered and up to date on vaccinations.We think he was born around 2005-2006. Must be an indoor only cat. He has had regular dental cleanings; last one was April of 2015. He would make a great companion for anyone who wants an affectionate kitty to love and care for."
          },
          "mix": {
            "$t": "no"
          },
          "shelterId": {
            "$t": "NC773"
          },
          "lastUpdate": {
            "$t": "2017-03-15T12:37:11Z"
          },
          "animal": {
            "$t": "Cat"
          }
        }        
      ]
```

and my code is

```html
<ol><li ng-repeat="pet in pets | orderBy: 'name.$t'">
<div>{{pet.name.$t}} - {{pet.animal.$t}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="pic in pet.photo">{{pic.$t}}</div>
</li>
<ul></ul>
</ol>
```

and pets = the JSON data above. The first ng-repeat works fine, the second one nested inside the first does not. originally I had it inside an img tag as ng-src and I thought it had something to do with the $sce source protection, but this doesn't work either so that doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Could you be more precise ? What do you mean by "does not work" ? What did you try ? What is the result you have now ? What is the result you're expecting to have ?

Comment: I was just testing to see if I could properly return the list of photos. Eventually I was going to have a gallery that one could navigate through, but I've realized I had my arrays mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the media type

```
<ol><li ng-repeat="pet in pets | orderBy: 'name.$t'">
<div>{{pet.name.$t}} - {{pet.animal.$t}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="pic in pet.media.photos.photo">{{pic.$t}}</div>
</li>
<ul></ul>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had it like that, but I also noticed that I had it as pet.media.photos and it needed to be pet.media.photos.photo. I'm an idiot